# My website stopped working due to Axios type error

Tags: javascript, axios

I had a working website that used Axios and now it does not work.
The error in the console says "TypeError: axios.get is not a function".
I am loading Axios on the client side from one of the normal CDNs.
What changed with this library and what do I do to get my site working again?

Here is minimal code to demonstrate the situation.

```js
/* eslint-env browser */
/* global api */

const api = (function(){
    const baseURL = "/api";
    const token = "fakeTOKENhere";
    const config = {headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }};

    return {
        ping: function(){
            return axios.get( baseURL + "/ping", config);
        }
    };
})();


api.ping()
.then( (response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    if(!response.data || response.data.status != "OK"){
        console.log("bad");
    } else {
        console.log("good");
    }
}).catch(() => {
    console.log("error");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>test code</h1>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/test.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5038. Pin [version 0.27.2](https://unpkg.com/browse/axios@0.27.2/)

Comment: In general, if it's not your code that's broken check the library maintainer's site before posting on StackOverflow. There's nothing anyone here can do other than offer temporary work-arounds

Comment: This is the best reason to never include a dependency from a CDN without specifying which version (also caching won't work properly). This time it was a bug, next time it might be a deliberate API change. Så pin a working version, then in the future upgrade to a newer version under controlled circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Temporary Fix

It appears [Axios v1.1.0 has a bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5038)

[Axios v1.0.0 has a different one](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4999)

You will have to use an older version of it for now.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.27.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

### use package managers

If you wish to not have similar issues in the future you could use `npm` or other package managers to download, and keep the version of these libraries in check. Otherwise you will always get the latest version, and issues like this can occur.

```
npm i axios@0.27.2
```

Comment: [What is the best way to deal with a temporal event which gets a lot of attention?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326252/283366). _TL;DR_ this question should just be closed. StackOverflow is not a support channel for Axios

Comment: The bug seems to be resolved, using `npm install axios@latest` or `yarn add axios@latest` should do the trick, and update the package to `1.1.1`. Not sure about the CDN versions