# Axios from browser not working but working from server

Tags: axios

I am using node.js and express to buil my server.
I have some routes from where I'm using axios without problem:
(axios instaled with npm i axios)

```
const axios=require('axios');

    const modelset=await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url:`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/modelset/v3/containers/${prIdSandbox}/modelsets`,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${internalToken.access_token}`,
                  },
                })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
    .then(function(res) { 
      return res.data.modelSets[0].modelSetId;
    })
```

Also I've using axios from a script loaded into my html page:

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ForgeTree.js"></script>
```

And the ForgeTree.js

```
const resources=await axios({
  method: 'get',
  url:`/api/forge/getDocuments/${containerId}/${modelSetId}/${version}`,
          })
  .catch(function(err) {
/* error in getting data */
console.log(err)
  })
...
```

It has been working, but suddenly it fails:

```
ForgeTree.js:139 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: axios is not a function
at getViewableModels (ForgeTree.js:139:27)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (ForgeTree.js:181:3)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:43064)
at v.handle (jquery.min.js:2:41048)
at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2:71515)
at S.fn.init.triggerHandler (jquery.min.js:2:72194)
at a.jstree.plugins.sort.trigger (jstree.min.js:2:12286)
at a.jstree.plugins.sort.activate_node (jstree.min.js:3:12893)
at a.jstree.plugins.sort.<anonymous> (jstree.min.js:2:8477)
at HTMLAnchorElement.i (jquery.min.js:2:88757)
```

It looks like if I have lost axios in the browser...could some one help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My website stopped working due to Axios type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73982722/my-website-stopped-working-due-to-axios-type-error)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const axios=require('axios');
```

to

```
const axios=require('axios').default;
```

It's major change for Axios 1.0 or you can change library path to https://unpkg.com/axios@0.27.2/dist/axios.min.js to use like it's use to.

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed without doing anything...stop working for one day...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).